# Rendering Flash Menu Over the Top of Game Drawn with copyPixels

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm new to flash but have plenty of experience developing games, so when I started in flash I ignored pretty much everything that flash could do and just created a buffer the same size as my flash movie and drew my game direct to that with copyPixels.

Now what I want to do is to add a menu to the game and it seems sensible to do make use of flash a little more.  I can build a menu no problems in a .fla but can anyone tell me how I can render it over the top of my game?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class for the menu and attach it via AS (also define it to your library in your IDE), and all it's functionality would be contained within that. I can provide a simple example, if you'd like.

Updated sample:

Create a class for your navigation - call it Navigation.as (same directory as your fla)

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public class Navigation extends Sprite
    {
        public function Navigation() 
        {
            addEventListener ( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );    
        }

        private function init ():void
        {
            // position your nav
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;

            // attach button functionality here
        }
    }
}
```

In your flash, right-click -> Properties, on your navigation MC in your library and do this:

```
Check "Export for ActionScript"
Baseclass:  "Navigation"
```

Then in your main AS, to add it to your stage, you can do this:

```
var _nav:Navigation = new Navigation();
addChild(_nav);
```

As long as your `addChild(_nav)` after your game is built, it will be on the top.

Hope this helps.

I can elaborate if needed.  Feel free to ask.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a noob at flash so bear with me...  I have a menu I'm happy with in a .fla (I imported images into the library then placed them in the editor and converted them into buttons).  The problem is that when I copyPixels my game to my buffer I draw over the top of the buttons.  I was hoping that I could request my menu items (or an entire layer) be rendered directly from script by calling a function after I render my game buffer.  Any simple examples would be great! :)

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample.  Lemme know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need something simple so just create a sprite and add it to the stage when you need your menus and remove it when you don't.

The way display objects work in flash you can build your whole menu in the Sprite (or Movie Clip) and it will be in one tidy place.